# Pause page refresh while displaying a modal

Tags: javascript, php, css, refresh, page-refresh

I am creating a webpage where auto refreshing the page is a necessity. I have used this code to refresh the page after every 2 seconds

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "2";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
</html>
```

Now when I want to confirm an action in the page, I want to display a modal to confirm the action. But the problem is the page refreshes and so is the modal. Is there a way the auto page refresh stops while the modal is displayed?

Note - The auto refresh stops when a javascript alert message is displayed.

Thankyou

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question.  If the purpose of the modal is to confirm the page refresh then the modal should also do the refresh and not use a meta. You could also add a timeout to refresh when the user fails to respond.

Comment: No no... The page auto refreshes. Now for example I want to logout, I want a modal to confirm the action. For that reason I need the auto refresh to stop momentarily when the modal is displayed or else it gets refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

When you activate your popup, call this code to stop the page from refreshing :

```
window.stop();
```

it will stop the page refresh whenever you will trigger the popup button, or automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a newbie here. Here is how I am calling the modal ```<li><a href="#end" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> END MOCK POLL</a></li>```. Should I include this here or in the modal code? Could you please show an example? Thankyou